I cannot decreasing space between row and page view
I am using a custom app bar and page view. I am trying to decrease the space between SortAndFilterRow and LibraryTabScreen. I don't use padding or margin or anything else that increases the space between the two of them. I tried using the Flexible widget instead of Expanded for wrapping the page view. This is the LibraryScreen page:
import 'package:feauthor/LibraryScreen/LibraryTabScreen.dart';
import 'package:feauthor/LibraryScreen/SortAndFilterRow.dart';
import 'package:feauthor/MainScreen/MainScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LibraryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LibraryScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _LibraryScreenState createState() => _LibraryScreenState();
}

class _LibraryScreenState extends State<LibraryScreen> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(
      index,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 40), // space for app bar height
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => _onTabTapped(0),
                  child: Text(
                    'KUTUPHANEM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.black : Color(0xFFC8C8C8),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => _onTabTapped(1),
                  child: Text(
                    'INDIRILENLER',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.black : Color(0xFFC8C8C8),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 24),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: SortAndFilterRow(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
              children: [
                // library page content
                LibraryTabScreen(),
                // downloaded page content
                Center(child: Text('İndirilenler İçeriği')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: LibraryScreen(),
));


And this is the LibraryTabScreen page:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LibraryTabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LibraryTabScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LibraryTabScreen> createState() => _LibraryTabScreenState();
}

class _LibraryTabScreenState extends State<LibraryTabScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7326, // value is changeable later
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7A7A7A)),
                    top: index == 0 ? BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7A7A7A)) : BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 56,
                        height: 87,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/examplebook.jpg',
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 12),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "WHAT WE SET IN MOTION",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Color(0xFF000000),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 12),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "STEPHANİE AUSTİN EDWARDS",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                fontSize: 15,
                                color: Color(0xFF000000),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 24),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text("Sayfa"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}



and this is my shortandfilterrow class codes

class SortAndFilterRow extends StatefulWidget {
  const SortAndFilterRow({super.key});

  @override
  State<SortAndFilterRow> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<SortAndFilterRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.filter_list_sharp, color: Colors.black, size: 30),
                    
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Filter operation
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        "Filtrele",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Color(0xFF000000),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.sort, color: Colors.black, size: 30),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Sort operation
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        "Sırala",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Color(0xFF000000),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
  }
}```







    


Problem seems to be at SortAndFilterRow(). Can you share that code?

yes of course i can share. i will update my question and add the short and filter row class codes.

All the code in the question so far did not reproduce the image. Try reproducing it with Dartpad then share the results.

i tried these codes in dart pad. and the code are working true. but it doesnt working true in my vscode and virtual phones

I tried it on desktop. Was getting errors trying to run on a phone, So I aborted it. Sorry.

I solved the problem thanks your helping

hi guys i found the reason of the issue. I recieved this error because i didnt used the fulls creen mode in my app. I added this code block and the space has been removed :
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky,
overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);//for full screen app


buddy To reduce the space between SortAndFilterRow and LibraryTabScreen, you can adjust the height properties of the SizedBox widgets and verify that there are no unnecessary paddings or margins. Specifically, you should focus on the SizedBox(height: 24) between SortAndFilterRow and the PageView. Here's how you can modify the LibraryScreen page to address this:
import 'package:feauthor/LibraryScreen/LibraryTabScreen.dart';
import 'package:feauthor/LibraryScreen/SortAndFilterRow.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LibraryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LibraryScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _LibraryScreenState createState() => _LibraryScreenState();
}

class _LibraryScreenState extends State<LibraryScreen> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(
      index,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 40), // space for app bar height
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => _onTabTapped(0),
                  child: Text(
                    'KUTUPHANEM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.black : Color(0xFFC8C8C8),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => _onTabTapped(1),
                  child: Text(
                    'INDIRILENLER',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.black : Color(0xFFC8C8C8),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12), // Adjusted height to reduce space
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: SortAndFilterRow(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
              children: [
                // library page content
                LibraryTabScreen(),
                // downloaded page content
                Center(child: Text('İndirilenler İçeriği')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: LibraryScreen(),
));


this not working. i tried it before. it is set space between short and filter row and tabs, but i want set space between short and filter row and page view i added a image for my question . thanks your help
